# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null in select2

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-select2

I am using `select2` in a node express app, and when I supply an array as data source `data: dataBase` I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null`.

I have tried using an ajax source as data, which works but the data are not filtered on typing (this is commented out below) - [it appears that matching only works with array data](https://select2.org/searching):

> matcher only works with locally supplied data (e.g., via an array! When a remote data set is used, Select2 expects that the returned results have already been filtered on the server side.

I am now building an array from the `ajax` GET call: `$.getJSON('/api/skills/all')`, and then providing this as the datasource in my `select2` call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Pre-populate search bar with selected items
    var skillsSelect = $('.select2-input');
    $.getJSON('/api/skills/user/')
    .then(function (selected) {
        for(var s of selected){
            var option = new Option(s.text, s.id, true, true);
            console.log(option)
            skillsSelect.append(option).trigger('change.select2');
        }
        skillsSelect.trigger({
            type: 'select2:select',
            params: {
                data: selected
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log("$.getJSON('/api/skills/user/') failed " + err)
    })

    var dataBase=[];

    $.getJSON('/api/skills/all')
    .done(function(response) {
        console.log(".done response: " + JSON.stringify(response))
    })
    .fail(function(err){
        console.log("$.getJSON('/api/skills/all') failed " + err)
    })
    .then(function(alldata){

        $.each(alldata, function(i, skill){
            dataBase.push({id: skill._id, text: skill.skill})
        })

        console.log(".then dataBase: " + JSON.stringify(dataBase));


        $('.select2-container')
            .select2({

                data: dataBase,

                placeholder: 'Start typing to add skills...',
                width: 'style',
                multiple: true,

                createTag: function(tag) {
                    return {
                        id: tag.term,
                        text: tag.term.toLowerCase(),
                        isNew : true
                    };
                },

                tags: true,
                tokenSeparators: [',', '.']
            })
    })
});
```

`console.log(".then dataBase: " + JSON.stringify(dataBase));` prints:

```
.then dataBase: [
{"id":"5c9742d88aab960fa7ca3d22","text":"perl"},{"id":"5c9742e18aab960fa7ca3d23","text":"python"},{"id":"5c9744b9f042ad10ae6240b7","text":"drinking coffee"},{"id":"5c974be7fdae0712996657a4","text":"communication"},{"id":"5c974df73957e012afdd2591","text":"data analysis"},{"id":"5c979fcdbd5d082e0a5f6930","text":"reading"},{"id":"5c97bdd5500aa73961237dc9","text":"analysis"},{"id":"5c97bea16daa4639b441abe8","text":"writing"}
]
```

Here is the stack trace of the error:

```
select2.full.js:4928 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
    at stripDiacritics (select2.full.js:4928)
    at matcher (select2.full.js:4964)
    at DecoratedClass.SelectAdapter.matches (select2.full.js:3411)
    at HTMLOptionElement.<anonymous> (select2.full.js:3271)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:354)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:189)
    at DecoratedClass.SelectAdapter.query (select2.full.js:3262)
    at DecoratedClass.Tags.query (select2.full.js:3700)
    at DecoratedClass.<anonymous> (select2.full.js:598)
    at DecoratedClass.Tokenizer.query (select2.full.js:3803)
```

Which is this function:

```
function stripDiacritics (text) {
    // Used 'uni range + named function' from http://jsperf.com/diacritics/18
    function match(a) {
        return DIACRITICS[a] || a;
    }
    return text.replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, match);
}
```

**I'm using select2 v4.0.6:**

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.1/js/select2.full.js

Comment: `.replace` doesn't occur anywhere in your code sample. Can you use the stack trace to show where the error is originating from?

Comment: @JamesMonger I've added it to the question

Comment: Which version of `select2` is used?

Comment: @raina77ow - v4.0.6 - I've updated the question to include this

Comment: did you check if there is data on this part `$.map(data, function(obj) {` ? did you put I break point and run this on console?

Comment: @HudsonPH The part that's commented out on my code?

Comment: yes, this is the problem no?

Comment: Can you use unminified select2 so you'll be able to place a breakpoint in stripDiacritics function? Looks like your `dataBase` is not of valid format for select2 to use, anyway; can you show its structure?

Comment: @HudsonPH No, that was just to show sourcing the data with ajax (which works but is unfilterable according to the docs). I've removed the commented out section for clarity

Comment: I made a test here from what you inform but there is no problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem on part that you inform, maybe is the position of you jquery or timeout and you are getting empty value:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var dataBase = [
{"id":"5c9742d88aab960fa7ca3d22","text":"perl"},{"id":"5c9742e18aab960fa7ca3d23","text":"python"},{"id":"5c9744b9f042ad10ae6240b7","text":"drinking coffee"},{"id":"5c974be7fdae0712996657a4","text":"communication"},{"id":"5c974df73957e012afdd2591","text":"data analysis"},{"id":"5c979fcdbd5d082e0a5f6930","text":"reading"},{"id":"5c97bdd5500aa73961237dc9","text":"analysis"},{"id":"5c97bea16daa4639b441abe8","text":"writing"}
];
    $('.select2-container').select2(
{

                data: dataBase,

                placeholder: 'Start typing to add skills...',
                width: 'style',
                multiple: true,

                createTag: function(tag) {
                    return {
                        id: tag.term,
                        text: tag.term.toLowerCase(),
                        isNew : true
                    };
                },

                tags: true,
                tokenSeparators: [',', '.']
            }
);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.1/js/select2.full.js"></script>

<select class="select2-container" style="width:200px;">

</select>
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me solve the problem: one of my array items had a null value.

Comment: Ran into this too. Some of the options had text-values of null.